# ##[warning]SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, pipeline, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have this issue when I try to run pipeline in Azure DevOps, I work with selenium + cucumber + java.

I have this error message :

```
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
```

Almost I upgrade th uuid

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
        <selenium.version>4.14.0</selenium.version>
        <log4jcore.version>2.20.0</log4jcore.version>
        <log4japi.version>2.20.0</log4japi.version>
        <cucumberjava.version>7.14.0</cucumberjava.version>
        <cucumberjunit.version>7.14.0</cucumberjunit.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>5.5.2</webdrivermanager.version>
        <junitplatform.version>1.8.1</junitplatform.version>
        <ngwebdriver.version>1.0</ngwebdriver.version>
        <json.version>1.1.1</json.version>
        <csv.version>1.1</csv.version>
        <pdf.version>1.8.1</pdf.version>
        <jira.version>0.5</jira.version>
        <testng.version>6.14.3</testng.version>
        <seleniummanager.version>4.12.1</seleniummanager.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${seleniummanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.rcarz</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${ngwebdriver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4jcore.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4japi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumberjava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumberjunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>${pdf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${csv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven
            defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see
                https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see
                https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>

                <!--plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin-->

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <xmlOutputDir>${project.build.directory}/surefire</xmlOutputDir>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see
                https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
            https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go the directory of your project that the **`package.json`** file is in, then try the following things:

1. Delete the file **`package-lock.json`**.
2. Run below command lines.

   ```bash
   npm cache clean --force
   npm install uuid@latest --force
   ```

On the **`npm install`** command, you also can specified a particular package version to install like as below.

```bash
npm install uuid@9.0.1 --force
```

Comment: [ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests

Comment: [WARNING]
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 2 plugin(s)
[WARNING]
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2

Comment: [ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\MargueriteQaAutomation\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests

Comment: @zdha, How about run the same build and publish processes for the same project on your local machine?